# Sidebar Demo - replaceSubview

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nssplitview

I have NSSplitView with divider style set as thin and it looks great.
[image]

However, if I replace one of a subviews with this line of code

```
[self.horizontalSplitView replaceSubview:[[self.horizontalSplitView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] with:myGreatView];
```

The divider looks kind of bad, how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint in XCode, or log the frame rects of the left column view before and after the change - observe if the frames are identical before and after the exchange occurs. Is the replacement view of the same class it's replacing?

Comment: Frame differs, but even if I set the frame before replacing subview `NSRect prevFrame = [[self.horizontalSplitView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    self.sideBarViewController.view.frame = prevFrame;` it does not help. Well it is not the same class per se, it's a subclass of NSView

Comment: One thing to check is the autoLayout attributes. If the frames are different, the clearly it's a layout issue - and if you know you're setting the frames properly, then clearly someone else thinks otherwise (somewhere out of scope). If the original view and the view you're replacing it with have, for example, different autoLayoutMasks, you may see this kind of behavior as the superview tries to layout the views according to their respective anchor and resizing characteristics.

Comment: autoLayout is trun off, and autoresizingMask's are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your view (`myGreatView`) has a border. Set the border type to `NSNoBorder`.

```
[myGreatView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
```